# What is the syntax for declaring role capabilities in WP

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication, widget, sidebar

I am using a plugin called Sidebar Login for Wordpress, and when configuring it as a widget, it allows you to declare what roles are able to see certain links:

(Text | HREF | Capability)

ex: (Dasboard | %admin_url% | admin, editor, author, contributor)

However, the documentation doesn't tell me what syntax to use when declaring what roles are able to see each link, and the support forums are dead. Using what I've written above just listing the roles, makes the link disappear for all roles. The same happens with everything I've tried and I'm wondering if there's some sort of universal syntax used, which would explain why it wasn't included in the documentation (because it's common sense to most). I am not familiar with this however.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the plugin code it's using the capability, not role. If you check the WP docs (http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) under each role it lists capabilities that role has. Those are what you need to use.

As an example, use edit_posts instead of Editor.